# Rails Active Record Statement Invalid Undefined column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm completely new in using ruby on rails and active record.
I cant seem to figure out why I keep getting this error. I am trying to delete soccer teams through the destroy method and it wont work. Here is what the full error says:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column matches.team_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "matches".* FROM "matches" WHERE "matches"."team_id" ... ^ ):`
Each match has two teams and a team can have many matches and players, here's what the classes looks like:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :players , dependent: :destroy
    has_many :matches, foreign_key: "team_id", dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teamA, foreign_key: "team_id", class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :teamB, foreign_key: "team_id", class_name: "Team"
end
```

```
class CreateMatches < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :matches do |t|
      t.references :teamA, foreign_key: { to_table: :teams }
      t.references :teamB, foreign_key: { to_table: :teams }
      t.index: :teams, :teams_id, unique: true
      t.boolean :state
      t.string :result

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What seems to be the issue?
I used foreign keys to try and make these associations work, since I saw a few posts that recommended it but it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: There is no team_id on the matches table, there are teamA_id and teamB_id columns. Your current approach requires two set of matches for each team.

Comment: You probably want to add a join table for `TeamMatches` (just match_id and team_id) you can then associate Teams and Matches through this table.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, there's no `team_id` column in you team but there is `teamA_id` and `teamB_id` and if you specify them seperately, you'll be able to call `#destroy`

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :matches_as_A_team, foreign_key: "teamA_id", class_name: 'Match', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :matches_as_B_team, foreign_key: "teamB_id", class_name: 'Match'. dependent: :destroy
end
```

But it's not a great design, to be frank. I'd suggest a different approach... perhaps a matches table, a teams table, and a join table 'matches_teams' that belongs to both a match and a team. You could put information about the team's role in the match in the join table itself (e.g. a boolean 'home' that's true for the home team, false for the away team.

Comment: It would kind of make sense to have two associations to the same table if the columns had some kind of inherent meaning like home_team_id/away_team_id but not when it is just arbitrary what goes where.